# split a column into multiple columns - tidyr - error

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to split the first column based on `.` using `separate` function from `tidyr`.

However, I am unable to split as I wanted. I included a sample input and the code I tried.

I have also tried using `extra` parameter but I couldn't able to get the desired output.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

input

```
var       name      tis      score
1       c.1.2.mi1.mi1_dup1.er.er2.er33.0..      t1      9.382828892992
2       c.2.2.mi1.mi1_dup1.er.er2.er33.0..      t2      99.382828892992
3       c.3.2.mi1.mi1_dup1.er.er2.er33.0..      t3      19.382828892992
```

output

```
1       c       1       2       mi1     mi1_dup1        er      er2     er33    0      t1      9.382828892992
2       c       2       2       mi1     mi1_dup1        er      er2     er33    0      t2      99.382828892992
3       c       3       2       mi1     mi1_dup1        er      er2     er33    0      t3      19.382828892992
```

code

```
input %>% separate("name", ".")
```

error

```
Warning message:
Too many values at 6 locations: 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't named the 11 output columns:

```
> input %>% separate(name,into=letters[1:11], sep="\\.")
  var a b c   d   e    f  g   h    i j k tis     score
1   1 c 1 2 mi1 mi1 dup1 er er2 er33 0    t1  9.382829
2   2 c 2 2 mi1 mi1 dup1 er er2 er33 0    t2 99.382829
3   3 c 3 2 mi1 mi1 dup1 er er2 er33 0    t3 19.382829
```